# I have a problem with C++Builder in 64 bits and Clipboard

Tags: c++builder

I have a problem with C++Builder in 64 bits and Clipboard.
Answer: Unsupported clipboard problem.
However, the Clipboard works in 32 bits.

The same 32-bit program worked very well.
But in 64 bits it responds: Unsupported clipboard problem.

```
// one image is pre-loaded
       TBitmap *BMP = new TBitmap();
    BMP->Assign(Clipboard());
    Image1->Width= BMP->Width; ImageVue->Height= BMP->Height;
    Image1->Picture->Bitmap->Assign(BMP);
    delete BMP;
```

Thanks

Comment: `Unsupported clipboard problem` is not a standard VCL error message.  Did you mean `Unsupported clipboard format` instead? What format(s) are actually on the clipboard? `TBitmap` supports only `CF_BITMAP`+`CF_PALETTE`

Comment: The SVG image is recovered in a CppWebBrowser, by the Clipboard then converted into BMP. All this works programmed in 32 bits but not in 64 bits.

Comment: Do `Clipboard()->HasFormat(CF_BITMAP)` and `Picture->SupportsClipboardFormat(CF_BITMAP)` return true or false under 64bit? If they are true in 32bit but false in 64bit then something is wrong in the VCL, you will have to enable Debug DCUs and trace into the VCL source code to figure it out.